# Is there a simple term to describe the shape of 1 - |cos x|

Tags: trigonometry, terminology

I have a metric that produces the shape $1 - |cos(x)|, x \in [0, \pi]$, see below:

[image: 1 - |cos(x)|]

If the shape were $sin(x)$, one would call it sinusoidal. What would this shape be called? Truncated inverse sinusoidal? Is there a more concise term?

Comment: There's no mathematical term for this specific shape. Mathematicians would be perfectly happy to call it "the graph of $y=1-|\cos(x)|$ for $x \in [0,\pi]$" and leave it at that.

Comment: First off, if you replaced $\cos$ with $\sin$, it would not be sinusoidal.  A sinusoidal curve is the graph of a function of the form $A\sin(\omega x + \varphi) + B$.  Using basic trigonometric identities, we could replace the $\sin$ with a $\cos$.  The function you show is not sinusoidal, as it cannot be written in the above form.  To my knowledge, it has no particular name, though I might describe it as a "periodic function with cusps".

Comment: @XanderHenderson - Morgoth called the graph of $y = \sin x$ sinusoidal, not $y = 1-|\sin x|$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Then I was/am confused---I thought that he was suggesting that if $\cos$ were replaced with $\sin$, then the graph would be sinusoidal.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I was saying $sin(x)$ is to sinusoidal as $1 - |cos x|$ is to _________.

Comment: Perhaps if you could tell us *why* you want a name for this curve, we could be more helpful. if it is just to refer to this curve, then Lee Mosher is not only right, he is far more right than you are. Names should clarify, or perhaps abbreviate, and I cannot see where any name you give it could accomplish either. If you are looking for a classification - a family of curves this one falls in, then Xander Henderson is right, but it may not be a classification useful to you. There we would definitely need to know more to give a better answer.